# Jenkins test Email Configuration via SMTP (Connection or outbound has closed)

Tags: java, jenkins, smtp, office365, ubuntu-18.04

I am getting the following error while testing sample mail in Jenkins.

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:976)
    at com.sun.mail.util.TraceOutputStream.write(TraceOutputStream.java:114)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2104) ...
```

SMTP configurations are as follows:

1. SMTP server : smpt.office365.com
2. PORT : 587 (also tried with 25,465 Note : all possible ports as suggested over net)
3. SSL unchecked
4. Added enable tls in Jenkins.xml
5. JDK (OpenJDK8,11 and Oracle JDK)
6. OS : UBUNTU 18 and elementary OS 5
7. Remaining Jenkins configures have been given properly.
8. Same configuration Jenkin test mails are working in Windows 10 platform.

I expected the mail to be sent to office 365 account but it is giving error:

> java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for the above issue.
The issue was emailer plugin 2.14. I downgraded to 2.13 and it works for the above configuration.